# F# FSharpMap vs Dictionary performance

Tags: algorithm, performance, f#, dictionary

I was wondering how does the F# immutable Map perform against the standard Dictionary.

I am writing a count function (for each line lookup increment set) to use on large files with millions of lines and thousands of elements.

What about the memory usage?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I was wondering how does the F# immutable Map perform against the standard Dictionary.

See [Visual F# 2010 for Technical Computing](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/products/fsharp_for_technical_computing/?so) pages 241-242 "Optimization: Use mutable data structures". Shows a `Dictionary` running 5-40× faster than a `Map` in the very similar setting of counting the frequencies on ints as a function of the number of unique keys.

In general, purely functional data structures like `Map` are not only extremely slow in the serial case but they destroy scalability of entire parallel programs. I gave [a lecture](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/agile-testing/jon-harrop-qr-decomposition) on this recently.

BTW, don't forget there is a `Seq.countBy` function!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how they should destroy scalability on prarallelle computation? You can read there data without typical errors from concurrent systems. The only thing that can be a pain is how the update policy should be

Comment: The problem with purely functional data structures in the context of multicore parallelism is that they allocate heavily and, consequently, burden the GC and CPU caches which are single shared resources.

Comment: You assume, that we need to use a GC. You can make pure functional programming in C, hence no garbage collection if you mean an automated one. Even so, functional structures can be implemented to limit overhead in respect to copying and cleverly implemented it will also boost performance of the structure. Yes purely functional structure do have a overhead compared to imperative once, but it also give you some benefit that simplify code, and doing well will make massively concurrent programming more performant and less error prone. This is of course dependent on the problem we need to solve