# How make .NET Mutable Dictionary<T, T> with StructuralComparison & Equality in F#

Tags: dictionary, f#, structural-equality

I Know F# have the MAP, but I wanna use the .NET Dictionary. This dict have key as string and values as F# values + the dict, ie:

```
type ExprC = 
    | StrC of string
    | BoolC of bool
    | IntC of int32
    | DecC of decimal
    | ArrayC of int * array<ExprC>
    | RelC of RelationC
and RelationC = Dictionary<string, ExprC>
```

Now, the problem I wanna solve is how provide the RelationC type with structural equality. If is required to encapsulate the actual storage, how create a container that is a replacement for Dictionary, use it for mutable operations and have structural equality?

---

With the current answer, this code not work (of curse the implementation is not complete, however, this not even compile):

```
[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>]
type MyDict() =
    inherit Dictionary<string, ExprC>()
    override this.Equals x =
        match x with
        | :? MyDict as y -> (this = y)
        | _ -> false

    override this.GetHashCode () =
        hash this

    interface System.IComparable with
      member x.CompareTo yobj =
          match yobj with
          | :? MyDict as y -> compare x y
          | _ -> invalidArg "MyDict" "cannot compare values of different types"

and [<StructuralEquality;StructuralComparison>] ExprC =
    | IntC of int
    | StrC of string
    | MapC of MyDict
```

This is the error:

> Error FS0377: This type uses an invalid mix of the attributes
>   'NoEquality', 'ReferenceEquality', 'StructuralEquality',
>   'NoComparison' and 'StructuralComparison' (FS0377)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a particular reason for wanting to do this with `Dictionary` rather than `Map`?

Comment: Performance. .NET dicts are way faster (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396196/f-fsharpmap-vs-dictionary-performance). In my use-case, I will need a lot of it. Plus, curiosity. I think is usefull to know how turn in a good citizen a .NET class ;)

Comment: Have you profiled and found a performance problem or are you guessing there will be a problem in the future?  If you don't know for sure if it's a problem, don't make your life difficult.  Do it the obvious way and solve the problem later if you need to.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant

Comment: For your latest issue, you can remove all of the attributes (for class types like `MyDict` they are not applicable, which is why you're seeing the error; for discriminated unions the attributes you're using just reflect the default behavior anyway).

Comment: So why the F# native map work? At the end, I just wish to have Dictionary behind the scenes to manage the data, but work with the recursive type declaration

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely *must* use `Dictionary<string, ExprC>`, you could derive from `Dictionary<'k, 'v>` and override `Equals`:

```
type MyDict() =
    inherit Dictionary<string, ExprC>()
    override this.Equals x =
        true // real implementation goes here
    override this.GetHashCode () =
        0 // real implementation goes here
```

Here, you'd need to implement `Equals` to have structural equality, and you'll need to implement `GetHashCode` to match you `Equals` implementation.

Another alternative, if you don't need the concrete class `Dictionary<'k, 'v>`, is to define your own class that implements [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea).

While possible, this sounds like a lot of work. It'd be much easier to use a `Map`, which has structural equality by default:

```
let m1 = Map.ofList [("foo", 1); ("bar", 2); ("baz", 3)]
let m2 = Map.ofList [("bar", 2); ("foo", 1); ("baz", 3)]
let m3 = Map.ofList [("bar", 2); ("foo", 1); ("baz", 4)]

> m1 = m2;;
val it : bool = true
> m1 = m3;;
val it : bool = false
```

Comment: In addition, one could define a structure holding a mutable reference to a `Map`. Calculating equality would then become really easy.

Comment: How do this with a structure?

Comment: You can't derive from a value type.

Comment: Now I get confused. What is need to fill in "// real implementation goes here"? Where I can look what kind of code I must do?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question at the end of the updated original post: What is the reason for "This type uses an invalid mix..."? This is a bug in the F# compiler, the error message is misleading, [see Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/960). The solution is to simply remove all attributes from `MyDict`.