# why does performance improve when using `static let` over `static member`?

Tags: .net, collections, f#

Not only did I see an improvement in performance after switching to `IDictionary` from `Map` (which is explored [in a question from over 10 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3396411/22944)), I got even more speed when I went from this `type`:

```ml
type MyCollection =

    static member Collection = [
        (1, "one")
        (2, "two")
        ...
    ] |> dict

    static member Get id = MyCollection.Collection[id]
```

…to a type like this:

```ml
type MyCollection() =

    static let collection = [
        (1, "one")
        (2, "two")
        ...
    ] |> dict

    static member Get id = collection[id]
```

Why does performance improve when using `static let` over `static member`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the difference if you look at the decompilation in [Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfALgTwA4FMAEBZVAwgPbDCYDGyAlkQHYAUAlNgLwCwAUNt9hMgIbVy2ALaYRAI0wAnbMVIVqdVtk4912ANpqNu+gEYo2AER1Mxxjt3r6AJiPHkAdyIWrGgLrZEAPmwwqSk53PkFA0XEpWQBxTGRsKhgVfHkyShpaADpUxQzNRI93TjQsPEISNKVaWyZWYK4eUKFsMnjyCtzlFlUG3W1e624DBzM3AcG7B2dXS3GeL19/QOR69SbwsUkZbFj4xJV2hXS6fJgPIA===)

`static member Collection` compiles to a property with a getter. i.e. it is syntactic sugar for `static member Collection()` hence when you call MyCollection.Collection it creates a new `IDictionary` every call.

By contrast `static let collection` is essentially a standard binding to a value with special auto-initialisation code. It only creates the `IDictionary` once.